# Using SquashFS to edit a Live CD?

Tags: customization

I've been messing around with [Ubuntu Customization Kit](http://uck.sourceforge.net/) recently and I would like to create my own bash scripts to customize Ubuntu ISOs. How would I use SquashFS to edit mount and edit the iso?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A [three-part Paranoid Penguin series in Linux Journal](http://www.linuxjournal.com/magazine/paranoid-penguin-customizing-linux-live-cds-part-i) entitled *Customizing Linux Live CDs* will probably be helpful.

It explains how to tinker with a live CD's SquashFS for the purpose of improving security. But I'm sure the instructions can be used to make other modifications as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about SquashFS, but you could use ISO Master (available from the ubuntu software centre) to edit ISO images.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use squashfs to edit a filesystem.  Squashfs is a filesystem and also the program that creates and extracts a filesystem.  If you want to customize your live CD, check out:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomizationFromScratch
- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization

You can mount a squashfs filesystem, but you cannot edit it.  Squashfs is a readonly filesystem, so to edit it you will need to extract it first.